# How to url redirect/rewrite .asp into .aspx

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic, url-rewriting

I'm running in the Cassini developer server inside Visual Studio 2012, and I need to redirect clients from the legacy `.asp` pages to `.aspx` pages.

**Note:** Ideally I would **redirect** clients from `.asp` to a friendly url, and then internally do a **rewrite** to `.aspx`

```
POST /ResetClock.asp

HTTP/1.1 307 Temporary Redirect
Location: //stackoverflow.us/ResetClock
```

And then internally:

```
POST /ResetClock
```

rewrites into `/ResetClock.ashx` (Yes, I changed it to `.ashx`; that's the virtue of url rewriting).

## Like what Hanselman did

This is a lot like [what Scott Hanselman did](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/RedirectingASPNETLegacyURLsToExtensionlessWithTheIISRewriteModule.aspx):

- Request for `/foo.html`
- gives the client a redirect to `/foo`
- client request for `/foo`
- is re-written into `/foo.html`

## The attempted hack

I tried the hack solution; alter the `.asp` page to force a redirect to the `.ashx` (and live to fight with the url re-write syntax another day):

**ResetClock.asp**

```
<% 
   Response.Redirect("ResetClock.aspx")
   Response.End 
%>
```

Except that Cassini does not serve `.asp` pages at all:

> ## This type of page is not served.
>
> **Description:** The type of page you have requested is not served because it has been explicitly forbidden.  The extension '.asp' may be incorrect.   Please review the URL below and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> **Requested URL:** /WebSite/FetchTimes.asp

Which points to a related issue. The solution I end up using cannot require anything that isn't already available on the IIS7.5. And it cannot require anything that needs access to the IIS Admin tools; and must exist entirely within the web-site (e.g. the `web.config`).

## The question

How do I re-write `.asp` into something more ASP.net-ish?

**Edit**: Changed `GET` to a `POST` to thwart nitpickers who wonder why the `307 Temporary Redirect` and not `302 Found` or `303 See Other`.

Comment: So, what's wrong with using IIS or IIS Express?

Comment: @JohnSaunders Nothing is wrong with using IIS. In the end the web-site will be deployed to an IIS7.5 machine. What won't fly is having to alter the configuration of the server in any way.

Comment: I meant using IIS Express on your development machine. The Visual Studio Development Server (which was developed from code named "Cassini", for those who don't know ancient history) simply isn't meant to do what you're trying to make it do. IIS Express _is_ meant to do what you want to do.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Presumably because it will require everyone else to install IIS Express on their development machines; or possibly require each developer to configure their machine in a particular way. Or because *"in order to do the conversion you will need to follow the steps below. Check out the solution file from source control. Unbind the web site from source control. Make the web server change. Rebind the web site in source control. If URL rewriting requires more than a change in the solution itself, then we'll leave the legacy system alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to create an `IHttpModule`. HttpModules let you intercept every request, and react as you desire.

The first step is to create the plumbing of an `IHttpModule`:

```
class UrlRewriting : IHttpModule
{
    public void Init(HttpApplication application)
    {
        application.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(this.Application_BeginRequest);
        application.EndRequest += new EventHandler(this.Application_EndRequest);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        //Nothing to do here
    }

    private void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication)sender;
        HttpContext context = application.Context;
    }

    private void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

And then register our *HttpHandler* in the `web.config` file:

**web.config**:

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <httpModules>
         <add name="UrlRewriting" type="UrlRewriting"/>
      </httpModules>
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Now we have a method (`Application_BeginRequest`) that will run every time a request is made.

## Issue client redirect if they ask for ASP page

The first order of business is redirect the client to a *"clean"* form. For example, a request for `/File.asp` is redirected to `/File`:

```
private void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication)sender;
   HttpContext context = application.Context;

   //Redirct any requests to /File.asp into a /File
   if (context.Request.Url.LocalPath == VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/File.asp"))
   {
      //Be sure to issue a 307 Temporary Redirect in case the client issued a POST (i.e. a non-GET)
      //If we issued 302 Found, a buggy client (e.g. Chrome, IE, Firefox) might convert the POST to a GET.
      //If we issued 303 See Other, the client is required to convert a POST to a GET.
      //If we issued 307 Temporary Redirect, the client is required to keep the POST method
      context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.TemporaryRedirect;
      context.Response.RedirectLocation = VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/File");
      context.Response.End();
   }
}
```

## And then the internal rewrite

Now that the client will be *asking* for `/File`, we have to re-write that internally to an `.aspx`, or in my case, an `.ashx` file:

```
private void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication)sender;
   HttpContext context = application.Context;

   //Redirct any requests to /ResetClock.asp into a /File
   if (context.Request.Url.LocalPath == VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/ResetClock.asp"))
   {
      //Be sure to issue a 307 Temporary Redirect in case the client issued a POST (i.e. a non-GET)
      //If we issued 302 Found, the buggy client might convert the POST to a GET.
      //If we issued 303 See Other, the client is required to convert a POST to a GET.
      //If we issued 307 Temporary Redirect, the client is required to keep the POST method
      context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.TemporaryRedirect;
      context.Response.RedirectLocation = VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/ResetClock");
      context.Response.End();
   }

   //Rewrite clean url into actual handler
   if (context.Request.Url.LocalPath == VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/ResetClock"))
   {
      String path = "~/ResetClock.ashx"; //no need to map the path
      context.Server.Execute(path, true);

      //The other page has been executed
      //Do not continue or we will hit the 404 of /ResetClock not being found
      context.Response.End();
   }
}
```

## IIS contains some basic url redirection

Starting with some unknown version of IIS, they added a (now mocked) form of URL Rewriting. It doesn't issuing a client redirect, only an internal re-write. But at least it could be used to solve my problem (responding to an ASP page with ASP.net content):

**web.config**

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <urlMappings>
         <add url="~/ResetClock.asp" mappedUrl="~/ResetClock.ashx"/>
      </urlMappings>
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

The client will still appear to have found a resource at `/ResetClock.asp`, but the guts of the response will have come from `/ResetClock.ashx`.

> **Note**: Any code is released into the public domain. No attribution required.